# \mathsurround added on both sides of tables when array package is loaded

Tags: tables

when the length `\mathsurround` takes a non-zero value, and when some packages (`array`, `tabularx`, and others) are used, a space equal to `\mathsurround` is inserted on both sides of the table.

Why such a behavior and is there any way to escape it (other than using `\AtBeginEnvironment{...}{mathsurround=0pt}`)?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\mathsurround=50pt % Exaggerated value to visualize the effect

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Each of the following packages adds a space equal to "\mathsurround" on either side of the table. Uncomment to see the effect.

% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{siunitx}
% \usepackage{cellspace}
% \usepackage{makecell}
% \usepackage{nicematrix}
% \usepackage{tabularx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

Bla bla $x=0$ bla bla.

Bla bla
\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
    A\\\hline
\end{tabular}
bla bla.

\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
        A\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a \mathsurround-user I've never noticed that phenomenon.  How did you detect it?

Comment: they all basically inherit from `array` package. I'm not sure that is intended....

Comment: The array package actually documents that mathsurround must be set to zero, and does set it to zero, inside a group where it has no effect.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I usually set the value of \mathsurround to 1pt. I noticed, when I used (for other reasons) the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package, that a table that was supposed to be left aligned was not perfectly. I wanted to find out what the problem was and after some trial, I found that it had something to do with `\mathsurround` and the `array` package.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/614

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this has been there since the start which seems a bit surprising, `\m@th` which resets `\mathsurround` seems mis-placed in `array.sty`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\mathsurround=50pt % Exaggerated value to visualize the effect


\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

Bla bla $x=0$ bla bla.


X\begin{tabular}{|c|}A$x$A\end{tabular}X

\makeatletter
\def\endtabular{\endarray\m@th$\egroup}
\makeatother


X\begin{tabular}{|c|}A$x$A\end{tabular}X


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you open a github issue so that this gets resolved with the next release?